# Is it possible to let users authorize email access in a web app using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, cookies, authorization

I've been looking into using cookies to create sessions and keep track of user privileges.
So, I made some basic code for a web app where you click a button, and the active user email is accessed.
Here is the google script (Code.gs):

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getUser(){
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  return email;
}
```

Here is the HTML script (Index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="recordUser()">Click me</button>
    
    
    
    <script>
      function recordUser(){
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(email){
           
           alert(email+ " is the user email.");
        }).getUser();
      }
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

[This is the HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqYf1.png)

"Authorization is required to perform that action." To my understanding, this means that every user of the web app has to somehow provide authorization to the google script allowing email access. So, I tried making the script have the scope of email info. This doesn't really work--and I didn't really expect it too.

[This is what my project properties > scopes look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4DfO.png)

So, is there any way to access active users via asking for authorization or through some workaround?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, not exactly sure what the problem is. If you have that code and publish as a web app, google handles the authorization, cookies etc.

Comment: Create an addon

Comment: @miturbe Sorry, I'll be more specific.  I'm just trying to get the email of a new user of my web app via a button click right now (In the future, I'll probably see if I can make it upon opening the web app).  However, when I run the website, 1) the button does not appear. 2) apparently the user needs to provide authorization to run .getActiveUser().getEmail().  So, I'm asking if there is a way to allow the user to provide that authorization, or if there is a better method.

Comment: @Cooper by creating an add-on, how would that help specifically?  I haven't made one before.

Comment: When you publish as web app, the user has to authorize before the page even loads. You cannot control when the user authorizes. Also if this is going to be a publc script, they will get a huge warning stating that the app is not verified... check out this example https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwKYmaZoAlYcNrr5FIVZVyfiFfBMJWCzRSjizjmU5hh0sMiOo6c/exec source:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/197oWwBDmB0iI3Ry9Km6mfO73Jjx9RWjXHI-bAM28bZs/edit#gid=0

Comment: About the comment above: **unless the credentials screen is verified** by Google, which is a fairly simple process. The problem with authorization still holds - if you let users in before authorizing, they will not get an opportunity to do so while in the app. You can, however, implement Google OAuth flow for [Server-side web apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#handlingresponse). Not a trivial task by all means, but plausible.

Answer (score 2):

`Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` returns the email of the current user, but there is a couple things that need to be done first:

**1.** When deploying your web app, in **Execute the app as:** select **User accessing the web app**.

**2.** Before executing the web app, the user has to authorize the web app to run on his behalf.

This should work, I already tested it.